# Passing data to EditorFor via ViewDataDictionary not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewdata

I'm trying to pass data via a `ViewDataDictionary` to a template-file in an extension-method for `HtmlHelper<TModel>`

```
var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary(helper.ViewData);
vdd["someValue"] = true;

return helper.EditorFor(expression, "_MyTemplate", vdd);
```

In my `_MyTemplate.cshtml` I try to access it

```
@{
    var myViewDataValue = ViewData["someValue"];
}
```

which is always `null` as my "someValue" is located under `ViewData.Values` where I cannot access it via it's name.

What am I missing here?

Using it directly in my view

```
ViewData["someValue"] = true;
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Start, "_MyTemplate")
```

is working. The same inside the extension-method fails as of in the `_MyTemplate` the `ViewData` has no "someValue" at all.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyExtension<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    helper.ViewData["someValue"] = true;
    return helper.EditorFor(expression, "_MyTemplate", helper.ViewData);
}
```

throws an exception:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: When you pass it like this `helper.EditorFor(expression, "_MyTemplate", vdd);` you basically pass model to your Tamplate have you tried `@model ViewDataDictionary` at the begin of your template and then use `var myViewDataValue = Model;`?

Comment: It's some kind of extended template for a `DateTime` object. So changing the model to `ViewDataDictionary` seems wrong (even if it would work). Any idea why it is not existing when setting it like `helper.ViewData["someValue"] = true;` but not passing it as parameter for `helper.EditorFor(expression, "_MyTemplate")`?

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyExtension<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    helper.ViewData["someValue"] = true;
    return helper.EditorFor(expression, "_MyTemplate");
}
```

to

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyExtension<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    helper.ViewContext.ViewData["someValue"] = true;
    return helper.EditorFor(expression, "_MyTemplate");
}
```

I thought `HtmlHelper.ViewData` and `HtmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData` are the same if not overridden somehow.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to why you need to do this?